copy column from one dataframe to another dataframe if IDs match and np.isclose is true
Here is my base DF I am working with.
d={'ID': [3,4], 'SHAPE.x': [340329.0,3329433.0], 'SHAPE.y': [3329.0,0]}
d2={'ID': [4,3], 'SHAPE.x': [3329600.0,340328.0], 'SHAPE.y': [111,222]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0,1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2, index=[0,1])

print(df)

ID    SHAPE.x  SHAPE.y
0   3   340329.0   3329.0
1   4  3329433.0      0.0

this is what I am trying to do but its not saving. I already know this is terrible with large datasets but it helps sometimes to write the logic out like this.
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row['ID'] == row2['ID']:
            if np.isclose(row['SHAPE.x'], row2['SHAPE.x']) == True:
                row['SHAPE.x'] = row2['SHAPE.x']
            else:
                pass

this is the result I am looking for:
ID    SHAPE.x  SHAPE.y
0   3   340328.0   3329.0
1   4  3329433.0      0.0

I have tried a few one liners like this below but its not giving the correct result. I dont think I want to do a merge though with the extra columns and I only want to copy one column over.
out = df.loc[(df['ID'] == df2['ID']) & (np.isclose(df['SHAPE.x'], df2['SHAPE.x']) == True), 'SHAPE.x'] = df2['SHAPE.x']

print(out)
0    3329600.0
1     340328.0


Can you explain what you are trying to do? Are you basically using one dataframe to filter the other dataframe?

If the ID column matches between two dataframes, I want to copy the value of "shape" column from the second dataframe over to the first dataframe. BUT only if the two shape columns are close in value. thats why i was trying to use this line: np.isclose(row['SHAPE.x'], row2['SHAPE.x']) == True

so what exactly is your desired output?

Can you have more than one value per ID?

the ID is unique. what do you mean one value per ID?

This one way to do it. Create a dictionary of your columns from df2, then use the np.where and map to insert the values in. This permits you to use the np.isclose.
dict_of_2nd = dict(zip(df2['ID'],df2['SHAPE.x']))
swap_shape = df['ID'].map(dict_of_2nd)
df['SHAPE.x'] = np.where(np.isclose(df['SHAPE.x'],swap_shape), swap_shape,df['SHAPE.x'])

print(out)


Doesn't this assume that there is a single value per ID?

@mozway, Yes this assumes that there is only one single value per ID

IIUC, you can use a merge_asof, this won't give you exactly the same comparison as np.isclose, but you could use a fixed threshold (5 in this example):
tmp = (pd.merge_asof(df[['ID', 'SHAPE.x']]
                       .reset_index()
                       .sort_values(by='SHAPE.x')
                       .add_suffix('_'),
                     df2.sort_values(by='SHAPE.x'), left_by='ID_', right_by='ID',
                     left_on='SHAPE.x_', right_on='SHAPE.x', direction='nearest',
                     tolerance=5
                    )
         .set_index('index_').reindex(df.index)
       )

df.update(tmp[['SHAPE.x']], overwrite=True)

Updated df:
   ID    SHAPE.x  SHAPE.y
0   3   340328.0   3329.0
1   4  3329433.0      0.0

Note on your code
For your code to work, you should use df.loc[row.name, 'SHAPE.x'] = row2['SHAPE.x'] to update the row, not row['SHAPE.x'] = row2['SHAPE.x'].

I like your answer.

for some reason I am not getting the result you have there. Just the shape.x from the first DF. 340329.0 and 3329433.0

@ajd018 this might depend on the pandas version, I updated with a hopefully more robust alternative. What is you version?

@ajd018 this is a very old version, if you can I'd really recommend to update (the current version is 2.2.2) ;)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d1 = {'ID': [3, 4], 'SHAPE.x': [340329.0, 3329433.0], 'SHAPE.y': [3329.0, 0.0]}
d2 = {'ID': [4, 3], 'SHAPE.x': [3329600.0, 340328.0], 'SHAPE.y': [111, 222]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1, index=[0, 1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2, index=[0, 1])

# Convert DataFrames to numpy arrays
np1 = df1.to_numpy()
np2 = df2.to_numpy()

# Sort the arrays by 'ID' to ensure alignment
np1 = np1[np1[:, 0].argsort()]
np2 = np2[np2[:, 0].argsort()]

# Check proximity using np.isclose and update SHAPE.x in np1 from np2
close_mask = np.isclose(np1[:, 1], np2[:, 1])

np1[close_mask, 1] = np2[close_mask, 1]

# Update df1 with the new SHAPE.x values
df1['SHAPE.x'] = np1[:, 1]

print(df1)
'''
   ID    SHAPE.x  SHAPE.y
0   3   340328.0   3329.0
1   4  3329433.0      0.0
'''

